# Get Simple price from Magento swatches options

Tags: php, magento, schema, price

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and have the following code within our custom > template > catalog  > product > view > type > options > configurable.phtml file.

```
<?php
$_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
$_weeeHelper = $this->helper('weee');
$_taxHelper = $this->helper('tax');
$_storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_id = $_product->getId();
$_weeeSeparator = '';
$_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
$_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
$_minimalPriceValue = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_minimalPriceValue));
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue,$_simplePricesTax);
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
if($this->getProductAttribute('special_price')){     
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel(); 
}else{     
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel(); 
}
$_finalPriceInclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice, true);
?>
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
    echo '<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">';
    echo '<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />';
    echo $_sku = '<meta itemprop="sku" content="'.$simple_product->getSku().'"/>';

    echo $_price = '<meta itemprop="price" content="'.Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, false, false).'"/>';

    if ($simple_product->isAvailable()):
   echo '<meta content="http://schema.org/InStock" itemprop="availability" />';
   endif;
   if ($_product->getAttributeText('att_condition') == "Yes"):
   echo '<meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />';
   else:
    echo '<meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/UsedCondition" />';
    endif;
   echo '<span itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">';
   echo $_name = '<meta itemprop="name" content="'.$simple_product->getName().'"/>';
   echo '</span>';

    echo '</span>';

}
endif;?>
```

We are using swatches to display the configurable items and also using an extension that switches the title, price and image when the swatch is selected.  All works fine, however as the changes are done in js I am unable to use these details.  So have created the above code and it cycles through the simple products and pulls out the necessary bits for Google schema.  great.  However I can't get the price right.  At the moment it's pulling the price from the configurable holder but I want it to take the price from the simple_product.

Any ideas? 
Thanks Jono

PS this is my first post of stackoverflow so please be nice ! lol

Comment: You might need to put `$finalPriceInclTax = $taxHelper->getPrice($simpleProduct, $convertedFinalPrice, true);` and the converted final price inside the foreach statement, and tell it to use the simple product instead (please note the variable naming changes in my example - stick to Zend style guidelines!).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on null in /home/fitting5/public_html/app/design/frontend/intenso/custom/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml on line 83